# Toggle nav that switches a banner section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built this toggle nav that switches a banner section between the slider and a map. All works well but I would like to know how I could improve my JavaScript as I am quite new to it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Banners Toggle
var bannerSlider = $('#banner_slider');
var bannerMap = $('#banner_map');

$('.thm-banner--toggles').find('a').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();

if ($(this).hasClass('toggle-map')) {
  bannerMap.css('z-index', '2');
  bannerSlider.css('z-index', '1');
}

if ($(this).hasClass('toggle-slider')) {
  bannerMap.css('z-index', '1');
  bannerSlider.css('z-index', '2');
}

});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I would change, without having anymore info about how the page is built, is from this

```
$('.thm-banner--toggles').find('a').on('click', function(e){
```

to

```
$('.thm-banner--toggles').on('click', 'a', function(e){
```

or this

```
$('.thm-banner--toggles a').on('click', function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you showed, it seems that there are 2 different links which remain always visible. Something like:

- `<a class="toggle-map">Show slider</a>`
- `<a class="toggle-slider">Show map</a>`

Keeping that kind of layout, it leads to a first suggestion: in each link replace the class by a `data-toggle` attribute, like this:

- `<a data-toggle="12">Show slider</a>`
- `<a data-toggle="21">Show map</a>`

Then the JS code reduces to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thm-banner--toggles a').click(function(){
    var toggle = $(this).data('toggle');
    $('#banner_map').css('z-index', toggle[1]);
    $('#banner_slider').css('z-index', toggle[0]);
    return false;
  });
});
```

(above, `return false` replaces `e.preventDefault`, so we don't need passing `e` to the handler)

In the other hand, from the user point of view it may seem a bit strange to keep the 2 links both visible: there is always one of them which has no sense because it proposes to show something already visible. So why not have a unique link like this:

- `<a class="thm-banner--toggle">Show ...</a>`,
  where "..." is "banner-slider" or "banner-map" depending on which one is currently hidden (merely changing banners ids to get different texts)

At the same time, apart if there is some other requirement in the layout, it might be more simple to alternatively show/hide the slide and map, rather than changing their `z-index`.

With the two ideas above the code becomes like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thm-banner--toggle').click(function(){
    var banners = $('#banner_slider, #banner_map');
    banners.toggle();
    $(this).html('Show ' + $(':hidden', banners)[0].id;
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks you for this input, really interesting to see how one can reduce the code. the two buttons need to stay visible, so the toggle method won't work for this instance. why return false, what does this do? going to see if the first method works for my project. thank you once again...

Comment: @user73142 _Returning false from a handler is equivalent to calling both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` on the event object._". Look at http://api.jquery.com/bind/#event-object.

Comment: Code does not work, I think you have a curly brace to many in there or something....

Comment: @user73142 Oops, sure there is a curly brace too, in both proposed methods. Corrected now: see the updated answer.